# External files not linking into HTML document

Tags: html, css, image

At first, the problem seemed to be that only my CSS file, which was linked into my HTML document, wasn't loading in the browser when opened, but then when integrating an image into the HTML document I found it also wasn't appearing in the browser when the document was opened (and I used Microsoft Edge, Chrome, and Firefox to open the document. All files are located in the same folder on my computer, and yet using relative paths to locate the files also seem to be doing nothing. The code looks as such. (Worth noting that I was messing around with both the background-image property in CSS and the  tag in HTML to load the same file since neither seemed to work)

**HTML Code:**

```
<head>
  <title>Quad Game Schedule</title>
  <link type="stylesheet" rel="text/css" href="displaylayout.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="fieldimg">
    <img src="field.png" alt="Field Overhead Image">
  </div>

  <div class="F1">
    <h2>Full Field Games</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>12:00 - TSPro vs Wings</li>
        <li>12:45 - Team Evanston vs Bosnia</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

**CSS Code (displaylayout.css):**

```
body {
  background-color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
  color: red;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

img {
  align-self: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.fieldimg {
  height: 30%;
  width: 45%;
  background-image: image(field.png);
  background-size: cover;
}

.F1 {
  align-self: center;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  width: auto;
}
```

In the browser developer side bar, it says that there are no style properties for the webpage, which can't be true. I can always write the CSS into the HTML document, but the image is also an integral part of the end product and that won't load either. (Also maybe worth noting, with text-color for the p element and body used in CSS was merely for testing purposes)

**Edit:** this is the exact code for the test files I made that still don't work.

**HTML:**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Webpage</title>
        <link type="stylesheet" rel="text/css" href="test.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>This is a test heading</h1>
        <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
        <img src="test.png" alt="Test Picture">
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    font-size: 24pt;
}

p {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

The image in the new folder for these test files was renamed as `test.png`.

**Edit 2:** I just found out that older files of mine that linked to external files still work, so the problem lies with the new files I make.

Comment: `link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"` you've switched the values.

Comment: That totally fixed the CSS, Thanks! Unfortunately the image still isn't working, any ideas?

Comment: I can only suggest passing it the full relative URL. If your image is in a different folder than your HTML file, give your img src the full relative path. You mentioned the image is in a new folder, so it would be `img src="newfolder/test.png"` assuming 'newfolder' is in the same folder as your html.

Comment: I've found that taking the img tag out of the div element fixed the issue, not entirely sure why it being under a div tag made it unable to locate the file, but as long as it works!

Comment: For what it's worth, your IMG tag should also be self-closing. Meaning it should end with `/>` instead of `>`

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are trying to load the image twice, once as a background image for the `div` with class `fieldimg`, and once inside it in an `  tag:

```
<div class="fieldimg">
  <img src="field.png" alt="Field Overhead Image">
</div>

.fieldimg {
  height: 30%;
  width: 45%;
  background-image: image(field.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

1.) The background image needs to have be defined like `background-image: url(field.png)`, not like you did it ("image(field.png)")

2.) The `height` setting for `.fieldimg` (30%) won't work, because there is no container around it that has a height setting to which the 30% could relate. So this becomes 0px high and therefore won't be visible. To avoid this you can apply `height: 100%` to the `body`

If you fix both, you'll have to erase either the background image or the image tag, otherwise you'll get your image twice...

Comment: I tried to put both instances of the image (CSS and as the img tag) to show the two ways I tried loading it, but it's my fault for not having made that clear. If I set the body to 100% height, does that mean I can then use relative height for the image/background-image? (I need to test out which one works best for my needs, but I can't test how it looks since the stylesheet won't load)

Comment: If you set the body to 100% height, you can set relative height to the `fieldimg` div. Then you can use a background image in that (background-size: cover or contain - try what you like better), or (witout a background) put the img tag in there and give the image 100% width and `height: auto` (or the other way round)

Comment: I tried fixing both the 2 instances of loading the image (field.PNG) as well as adjusting the body height, but when I load the document, no properties from the CSS file load, not even the text color. I'm sure this would fix the image, but the CSS file still won't load. Is it possible something is preventing it from loading?

Comment: if the css file is in the same folder as the HTML file, it should work that way. The only possible reason I can think of if it doesn't load anyway would be restricted file permissions on the CSS file, but that's not very likely.

Comment: All files are sitting in the same folder with no subfolders. PNG, HTM, CSS are all together. What are restricted file permissions?

Comment: That for some reason you don't have the permission to open/access a file - as I wrote: very unlikely, especially since you obviously can open it to edit it.

Comment: As posted by me in a comment below: "In a new folder I created a test.html, test.css, and test.png files (test.png was a copy of the original image). I also wrote the code in Notepad++ instead of Atom, as I had been using before. It STILL won't load any of the external files, the image or the CSS file. I tried it in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome. I have no idea what is wrong." I did this to see if something was wrong with the text editor, file location, or file names, but it's still the same issue

Comment: A question: Is that your complete code for the HTML file up there? (there are no opening and closing HTML tags and no closing body tag...)

Comment: I just added the "test" code into the original post as an edit. These files (test.html, test.css, and test.png) are all in a new folder on my desktop

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS contains an error that might be the cause:

```
.fieldimg {
  height: 300px; /* set an absolute amount of pixels here instead of a relative number (which is relative to nothing) */
  width: 45%;
  background-image: url('field.png'); /* this is how you place images by setting a background image */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Also, remember that when not using relative paths in your CSS it is relative to the location of the `.css` file! So if using an image as a background image in a specific CSS folder, be sure the image is relative to that CSS file location.

Comment: Thanks for the catch! All the files sit in the same folder (no subfolders), so there shouldn't be an issue locating the external files. Unfortunately using image() instead of url() doesn't seem to be the issue since it's still not loading any of the stylesheet when opened in a browser.

Comment: Ah in that case it's a conflict with the absolute height of the image. Set the .fieldimg height to a specific amount of pixels and you should be golden! Obviously, the image _will_ show twice, because you have specified it both as an img element and as a background image.
You also mentioned that _nothing_ of the stylesheet is showing? Like, does it even load _at all_?

Comment: Yeah, not even the text color. I've made the changes you've recommended but nothing's changing since the CSS file still isn't loading

Comment: That's a different issue altogether, have you tried refreshing the cache of your browser or trying to open it in another browser?
Are you absolutely sure the file names match?

Comment: Yeah, I've opened it in Microsoft Edge, Firefox, and Chrome and I get all the same thing. I've also tried changing file names in case for some reason they were invalid or matched some other file on my computer, but that's not the issue either. I'll try creating another test HTML and CSS file elsewhere on my computer and report back in a little bit

Comment: Alright, curious to hear from you! Let's solve this thing!

Comment: In a new folder I created a test.html, test.css, and test.png files (test.png was a copy of the original image). I also wrote the code in Notepad++ instead of Atom, as I had been using before. It STILL won't load any of the external files, the image or the CSS file. I tried it in Edge, Firefox, and Chrome. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: If you open the website in chrome and open de developer tools, does it show an error?

Comment: Yes: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.  None of the CSS is loading either though, and the styles in the developer tools bar are not what I put in, they have `display: block` and `margin: 8px` when I put in text color and size style rules

Comment: In that case are you absolutely sure you're editing the right files in the right folder, and not ones in a duplicate one? Sounds lame I know, but happened to me quite a few time.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure. I remade all the files in a test folder from scratch just to make sure

Comment: There's a problem somewhere and I'm afraid I don't have enough info to determine it from here I'm afraid... I suggest you simply inline the CSS and go from there for now, considering I'm out of options...

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I'm now suspecting it's something wrong with my computer/browser/settings rather than the code itself

Comment: No worries, hope you figure it out! Good luck!

Comment: @Woomfy Just thought of this whilst sleeping; have you tried checking if you accidentally made double extensions, such as _.css.css_ but Windows isn't showing extensions?